# Mudar a cor do site em um clique de botão!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Boas pessoal!
Eu tenho um botão com 5 botões, ao clicar nesses botões, a cor do site vai mudar, eu estava a fazer esse processo a alterar a cor em Javascript, mas não acho muito viável... Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Fazer 5 cópias do documento css original mudando assim só as cores e fazendo trigger com js? 
Qual será a melhor maneira de fazer isso, pessoal?

Comment: mudança permanente?

Comment: Sim, pelo menos até ao utilizador voltar a clicar noutro botao para mudar para outra cor, ou até o utilizador fazer refresh À pagina.

Comment: Então não é permanete, vc pode simplesmente usar `Jquery` e mudar quando clicar, quando atualizar ela volta ao normal

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o melhor a se fazer seria criar classes para cada cor (ex: dark, light, default) e quando clicar no botão altera apenas a classe do elemento pai, o resto ja esta definido dentro.

ex:

```js
var dark = document.getElementById('btnDark');
var light = document.getElementById('btnLight');
var initial = document.getElementById('btnInitial');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
dark.onclick = function(){
 body.className = "dark";
}

light.onclick = function(){
 body.className = "light";
}

initial.onclick = function(){
 body.className = "";
}
```

```css
.dark{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}

.light{
background:#fff;
color:#4b4b4b;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica.</p>
  <button id="btnDark">Dark</button>
  <button id="btnLight">Light</button>
  <button id="btnInitial">Default</button>
</body>
```

Utilize o sass para criar as classes, facilitaria muito mais.

PS: No exemplo acima não usei nenhuma biblioteca.

Comment: Boa ideia!
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Com `Jquery`:

```
<button id="red">Vermelho</button>
<button id="green">Verde</button>
<button id="blue">Azul</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('body').css('background-color',$(this).attr('id'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fiz isso, mas o problema que estu a a ter agora é que, tenho um titulo h2, esse h2 tem um after pseudo element, como mudo a cor do pseudo element do h2 com jquery?

Comment: @NelsonPacheco Não é possível. O que você pode fazer é criar um código CSS, por exemplo: `.your_class::after { /* Your Code */  }` e depois utilizar `addClass` ou `toggle` para alterar o CSS.